# AttachedProperty not recognized in XAML (compile error)

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I get build errors when I attempt to add an attached property to a listview control.

What's wrong with my code such that it does not build?

My code is the following:

XAML:

```
xmlns:attachedProperties="using:MyNamespace.AttachedProperties"
```

.

```
<ListView x:Name="ContactList" 
          attachedProperties:CategoryHelper.Category="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Code:

```
namespace MyNamespace.AttachedProperties
{
    public class CategoryHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CategoryProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Category", typeof(Category), typeof(CategoryHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyChangedCallBack));

        private static void OnPropertyChangedCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static void SetCategory(ListView listview, Category category)
        {
            listview.SetValue(CategoryProperty, category);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I get build errors when I attempt to add an attached property to a listview control*... care to provide us with the details?

Comment: i copied and paste the code it got build though a warning regarding the GetCategory method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the getter. It should look like this :

```
        public static Category GetCategory(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Category)obj.GetValue(CategoryProperty);
        }

        public static void SetCategory(DependencyObject obj, Category value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CategoryProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Category.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CategoryProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Category", typeof(Category), typeof(CategoryHelper), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

There the built in snippet `propa` you can use to generate properties.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see getter and setter for DependencyProperty like

```
public static void SetMyContent(DependencyObject obj, string val)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyContentProperty, val);
    }

    public static string GetMyContent(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(MyContentProperty);
    }
```

Comment: That's because it's an `AttachedProperty`